# PHP Optimization: Form Variables

Tags: php

Lets say I have a form with 30 fields. I was trying to think of a way to optimize a solution to check on the server side if all these fields are empty or contain a specific value and the them accordingly.

So, the code for 1 variable would be as follows:

```
if((!isset($_POST['usa_state_list'])) || (strcmp($_POST['usa_state_list'],'undefined') == 0)) {
    $usa_state_list = '';
}
else {
    $usa_state_list = $_POST['usa_state_list'];
}
```

Now imagine 30 of these fields, you'd have to have 30 of those `if` statements. Do you have an idea on how to optimize this? switch or for loop perhaps?
NOTE: Let's stick to this example where I check if the field is either empty or contain the `undefined` string.

Thanks

Comment: Just [an idea](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) ;-)

Comment: Que? I know what functions are... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a function and use it over and over. Simple example I just whipped up (hasn't been tested):

```
function checkPost($key) {

    // check if the element has been posted
    if(isset($_POST[$key])) {

        // check if element is empty
        if($_POST[$key] != '') {

            // check if the element contains a specific value
            if($_POST[$key] == 'my specific value') {

                // do whatever here...

            } else {

                // return the posted value
                return strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
            }

        } else {

            // POST value was empty
            // you could return an error message here...
            // or add to a global $errors array...
            return $key . ' is required';
        }
    }

    // the element has not been posted
    return false;
}

$usa_state_list = checkPost('usa_state_list');
$name = checkPost('name');
$address = checkPost('address');
```

Comment: Ah, simple enough, thanks tim! that sure helps a lot. :)

Comment: What then? `preg_replace`?

Comment: The funny part is that if I hadn't put in a cleaning function I would have been blasted for that too. :) Everybody has their own preference; and there's no pleasing everybody. You could read articles about cleaning input for hours and hours and still be confused. PHP has some good ones: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: To be honest I was actually thinking of `strip_slashes()` (sorry!). But handling arbitrary form input as HTML is a surprisingly common misconception.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ha! Yea, if I put in `strip_slashes()` I'd deserve to get blasted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Built-in [filter functions](http://php.net/filter) are only slightly verbose:

```
$usa_state_list = filter_form(INPUT_POST, 'usa_state_list');
```

... but since you need to do some custom post-processing and you need to output individual variables I think it's better to simply write your own:

```
function post($name) {
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name);
    if ($value!=='undefined') {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
$usa_state_list = post('usa_state_list');
```

Of course, if you think that code legibility is for wimps then the sky is the limit:

```
foreach (
    [
        'usa_state_list',
        'foo',
        'bar',
    ] as $name
) {
    $$name = post($name);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation of the `filter_form` function, however, I found docs for `filter_input`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php.

Comment: Does it even matter to sanitize here? I am using MySqli prepared statements. And as for your "pro code" I have never seen code like that so I better stay away for now :)

Comment: I've just fixed the typo, thanks for noticing it. As about sanitisation, my advice is that you never do it blindly. You've got to know what you want to protect yourself from.